How to reuse part of a graphql type?
Lets say I have the below schema:
type User {
  name: string
  location: Location
}

type Organization {
  industry: string
  size: number
  user: User
}

type query {
  organization: Organization
}

type mutation {
  updateOrganization(industry: string, size: number): Organization
}

Now when I mutation using updateOrganization I end up needing to send user field as well.
Is there a way to do something like
type mutation {
  updateOrganization(industry: string, size: number): Omit<Organization, 'User'>
}

I tried using interface like below, but that didn work well.
interface OrganizationFields implement Node {
  industry: string
  size: number
}

type Organization implements OrganizationFields {
  user: User
}


type mutation {
  updateOrganization(industry: string, size: number): OrganizationFields
}

Problem here is I need explicitly mention typename as __Organization when returning from updateOrganization which requires user also to be sent.

You should never send information about the current logged-in user as mutation variables - this should come from context

This is just a dummy example. The question is mainly to know how to send part of a type as result.
